# matplotlib makes line instead of normal scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataset, scatter-plot, scatter

i am trying to print scatter data of city companies, but it works only with one dataset, but not with other.
They are litterally same. example of both:

good:

```
lan,lon,comp
44.353243,48.791494,S7 Airlines
44.354418,48.79181,Аэрофлот-Российские Авиалинии
```

[image: Working dataset example]

bad:

```
lan,lon,comp
30.35767,59.924862,Авиадух
30.345738,59.932526,Аэрофлот
```

[image: Not working dataset example]

here is command

```
dataproceesed.plot(kind="scatter", x=0, y=1, alpha=1,s= 1,figsize=(16, 9), c="r")
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your lat/lon are discrete values in the second DataFrame, can you check with df.info() that these two columns are numerical, and not object type?

Comment: @dm2 yep. you were right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as @dm2 helped it was due to different type. In my case not only because of "NAN". solved with this:

```
listForDelete = []
for each in range(len(dataproceesed)):
    if dataproceesed["lan"][each] == 'undefined' or dataproceesed["lan"][each] == "0":
        listForDelete.append(each)
    if dataproceesed["lon"][each] == 'undefined' or dataproceesed["lon"][each] == "0":
        listForDelete.append(each)    

dataproceesed = dataproceesed.drop(listForDelete)
dataproceesed.dropna(inplace=True)

dataproceesed["lon"] = dataproceesed["lon"].astype('float64')
dataproceesed["lan"] = dataproceesed["lan"].astype('float64')

dataproceesed.info()
```